# Particle in a 2d box, using de broglie wavelength to find momentum of the particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider a proton in a 2-dimensional infinite potential box with widths, L and K.

a) Using de Broglie wavelength, find the momentum of the particle.

I find some online sources that finds the energy (not momentum) using the wavefunction and seperation of variables. But the question clearly states that we should find the momentum **using the de Broglie wavelength**

I am a bit confused actually. How can we find the momentum just using the wavelength ?

If the box was one dimensional, the momentum could be expressed as $p=hn/2L$ 
since we have 2 dimension we will have 2 momentum component ?

Can I express my solution as $p=p_x+p_y=hn/2K+hm/2L$ ?

I am thinking that this is wrong. But also thinking about what question asks, I get confused

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is a vector. The norm is given by $p=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2}$.

Comment: So I just have to take the norm of it ? And my answer is true ??